# Normal distribution, how to calculate $\mu$ and $\sigma$

Tags: normal-distribution

How to calculate $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ when it is known just that $P(X\le 49)=0.6915$ and $P(X>51)=0.2266$  ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: what do you know about the values of $\frac{X-\mu}\sigma$ ?

Answer (score 1):

I would say just the standard normal distribution table $P(U\le u) = \Phi(u)$:

$\frac{49-\mu}{\sigma}=\Phi^{-1}(0.6915)=0.5$

$\frac{51-\mu}{\sigma}=\Phi^{-1}(1-0.2266)=0.75$

Solving this system of equations: $\,\,\mu = 45,\,\,\sigma=8$.

Answer (score 0):

Just quickly, using *Mathematica* :

[image]